# Is it safe to ignore "Warning: Attempt to present ... while presentation in progress"?

Tags: ios, swift

When I call `viewController.presentViewController`, the following warning appears if another controller is already presented.

> Warning: Attempt to present ... while a presentation is in progress.

If the intended behavior is to do nothing if a presentation is already in progress, is it safe to just ignore the warning?

```
viewController.presentViewController(...)
```

Or must I check before presenting?

```
if viewController.presentedViewController == nil {
    viewController.presentViewController(...)
}
```

Comment: Where you presenting the view controller? is that in view did load?

Comment: where have you written this show the method where u are calling this

Comment: Obviously it's not safe to ignore any warning.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't ignore**.Because it means you are trying to present a view before the current viewcontroller appearence.If you ignored this warning, the next view can't able to present.

1.Check you not presenting any view controller before the current view loads(avoid `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` methods to present a nextview controller)Because it will **missing the ViewController hierarchy**

2.Try to present next view controller use `ViewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't ignore this warning. Actually you shouldn't ignore any kin of warning because warning can creates trouble in future. So, it is better to find solution for that warning.

Don't know your case that from where you are presenting you `VC` and Which `VC` is already presented. But, you required to code like this as first dismiss current presenred controller and then try to present new controller.

For example,

I am  explaining one case when you found this warning :

Assume that you are using `actionsheet` and on click of button of `actionsheet` you are presenting `newVC` and you are using `clickedButtonAtIndex` delegate method to present `newVC`.

In this case you will get this warning and unable to present `newVC` because `actionsheet` is already presented.

So solution of this case is : use `didDismissWithButtonIndex` delegate method of `actionsheet`. It is get called when user `press button` and `actionsheet is dismissed`.

So, you will not get warning and able to present `newVC`

Like wise check your case and see which VC is already presented and present newVC after successful dismiss of current presented VC.

Hope this will help :)